# Determine a Function $F(x,y)$ with the following properties over the Lebesgue-Borel measure

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

I have come across with the following question, find an example of a function $ F:  ℝ^2  → [0, 1] $, such that :
(i) $ x → F(x,y) $ is monotonically increasing for all $ y ∈ R $,
(ii) $ x → F(x,y) $ is increasing for all $ x ∈ R $,
(iii)there exists no measure $μ$ on $(R^2, B^2)$ with $ F (x, y) = μ((−∞, x] × (−∞, y]) $.

I am sure that in order to find this function i should think about the properties of Lebesgue-Borel measure or Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure but i am not quite sure and i have stuck in how i could combine all these 3 prerequisite. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I believe that in condition (ii) you meant: (ii) $ y → F(x,y) $ is increasing for all $ x ∈ R $.